# How to host a django website in my pc and view it in another pc?

Tags: django, web-hosting

I have a django project in my pc.

In terminal I've run `python3 manage.py runserver <my ipaddress>:8001`

When I try to open the link in another pc, it is showing error page which says:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '<my ipaddress>:8001'. You may need to add '<my ipaddress>' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

What should I do?

And moreover is it possible to put some text in place of ipaddress in the url?
For example, I want to host it as `myproject/` instead of that complex url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On one condition this will work

> if both computers are on the same network like local Hotspot or same
>   LAN network

steps:

1. add '*' in your django projects's setting file in Allowed Host it will look like

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

2. run your server on this ip `0.0.0.0` and port any like `8000` using this command

> manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

3. run `ifconfig` if you are using linux `ipconfig` if windows then you will get your ip address of your server
4. Open browser in another computer and enter the ip of server shown in 3rd step with port as `8000`

> http://ip-of-server:8000

Comment: Isn't it possible if both computers are not in same network?

Comment: yes it is possible using pagekite and ngrok they are localtunnel services that tunnel your localhost server to public ip then your server is accessible over public internet

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `<my-ip-address>` to the `runserver` command, pass `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I got this same error: 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8001'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS'

Comment: Don't put `0.0.0.0` in your web browser, just your normal IP. Also, ensure that the IP you're accessing is listed in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

Answer (score 1):

If both the machines are in the same network you can run the application on 0.0.0.0 IP address (refers to all IPv4 addresses on the local machine).  Refer this link [wiki 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) for more details. So, on application server run this:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Now, from the other machines, access it using http://youripaddresss:8001 , where < youripaddress > is the actual ip address of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If both computers are not on the same network (local hotspot or LAN network)

> You can use **ngrok** to view whatever is running on your localhost from any device

### Using ngrok to view your django project from any device

*follow the steps below:*

0. Add '*' in your django projects's setting file in Allowed Hosts:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

1. Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) from the official website
2. Unzip the downloaded file and then go to the directory where the ngrok file is located via your terminal
3. Then type the command:

```
ngrok http 8000
```

or

```
./ngrok http 8000
```

4. Now you can open the url generated by ngrok on any device to view what is running on your pc:
   `https://randomly_generated_subdomain.ngrok.io`

***PS:** this can also be used for any webserver running locally, not just django site*

##### ngrok is a great tool that can be used to:

- Run personal cloud services from your home
- Demo websites without deploying
- Build webhook consumers on your dev machine
- Test mobile apps connected to your locally running backend
- Stable addresses for your connected devices that are deployed in the field

Answer (score 0):

Run your server with this command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
Then you can access your website from any system connected to your wifi with an URL like `192.168.0.1:8000`
You may get your `IP Address` using this command in CMD `ipconfig` in windows and `ifconfig` in mac
Also add your `IP` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `setting.py`

Answer (score 0):

ALLOWED_HOST = ['*'] in your settings.py

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

then make sure your machine firewall allows incoming and outgoing traffic.
I use linux machine so from control center go to firewall and allow both incoming and outgoing.
then on your local network machine.
:8000

This is it !
worked for me

Comment: from local network machine. typed your host machine it then :8000